# How do you change a fetchRequest to an Array to use in a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am tying to put fetched data from coredata in a `UITableView` but I get this  "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" .
Using the let swiftBlogs Array works just fine, so can someone show my how to convert the fetch to an Array or is that not the correct way?

[image: UITableView]
[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet var timeStampTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var quickQuoteTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var tableViewQuickQuote: UITableView!


    let swiftBlogs = ["Ray Wenderlich", "NSHipster", "iOS Developer Tips", "Jameson Quave", "Natasha The Robot", "Coding Explorer", "That Thing In Swift", "Andrew Bancroft", "iAchieved.it", "Airspeed Velocity"]

    var tableViewCellArray : Array<AnyObject> = []
    var quickQuoteArray : Array<AnyObject> = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        var appDel: AppDelegate            = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var request                        = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "QuickQuote" )
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            tableViewCellArray             = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        quickQuoteTextField.text = ""
        timeStampTextField.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        quickQuoteTextField.text = ""
        timeStampTextField.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func addToQuickQuoteButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let appDel: AppDelegate            = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let ent                            = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("QuickQuote", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var newQuickQuote                  = QuickQuote(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            newQuickQuote.quickQuote       = quickQuoteTextField.text
        context.save(nil)
    }


    @IBAction func timeStampButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timeStamp()

        let appDel: AppDelegate            = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let ent                            = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Time", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var newTime                        = Time(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            newTime.time  = timeStampTextField.text
            newTime.quote = quickQuoteTextField.text
        context.save(nil)
    }


    func timeStamp (){
         timeStampTextField.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle,
         timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return swiftBlogs.count  // return quickQuoteArray.count
    }


    private let stampCellID: NSString = "cell"  //This is the cell itself's identifier.    
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(stampCellID as String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var data: NSManagedObject = quickQuoteArray[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
            cell.textLabel?.text    = data.valueForKey("quickQuote") as? String


//       let row = indexPath.row
//           cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]

        return cell

    }


/*
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var appDel: AppDelegate            = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            let tv = tableView
            context.deleteObject(quickQuoteArray.self[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

        }

        context.save(nil)
    }
*/

     func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up `quickQuoteArray` and `tableViewCellArray`, so `quickQuoteArray` is always nil.  In `viewDidAppear`, use `quickQuoteArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!` to load it with the results of the fetch.

Comment: I reworked it out by adding a fetchRequest and storing it an the array.

Comment: I reworked it out by adding a fetchRequest to the @IBaction addtoquiclquovebutton and storing it an the array. But had to change the array to a [NSManagedObject]    In the func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath i changed the code line of             var data  =     to      let qQuote = tableViewCellArray [indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = qQuote.valueForKey("quickQuote") as? String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your arrays swiftBlogs and quickQuoteArray. Whether or not the table view tries to access an array element `quickQuoteArray[indexpath.row]` is dependent on if it thinks that index is populated, based on the result from `numberOfRowsInSection`. In the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, you are returning the count of swiftBlogs, which is always the 10 or so strings you hand-typed in. So before your request is ever even executed, or the view even has a chance to populate anything else, it's trying to show elements that aren't present in the array you're using in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In short:
Always use the same array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as you are using in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Here, you've mixed two different arrays, quickQuoteArray and swiftBlogs.